# Summation notational convention

Tags: summation, notation

*Please correct improper notation/terminology*

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k$$. $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1}$$

As far as I can tell these both represent the same thing.  It's the partial sum {$S_n$} where the starting index is {$term_1$} with the initial value {$a$}, and the ending index is {$term_n$}.

**First question**
Is the difference between a partial sum vs using the summation notation {$\sum$} the fact that a partial sum always starts at {$term_1$} and adds sequentially left-to-right until {$term_n$}, as opposed to being able to start at any {$term_x$} using {$\sum$} while adding in any specified order?

**Second question**
In {$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k$}, {$k=0$} and {$n-1$} are implied to be direct exponent values of {$r$} for {$term_1$} and {$term_n$} shown respectively as {$ar^k$} and {$ar^{n-1}$}.

In contrast, {$k$} and {$n$} in {$\sum_{k=1}^{n}ar^{k-1}$} are implied to be direct term values - which can be shown as {$term_k$} and {$term_n$}.  Variables {$ar^k$} and {$ar^{k-1}$} seem to be the modifiers responsible for this change.

- What are the rules in notational convention governing this behaviour?
- Are {$ar^k$} and {$ar^{k-1}$} variables representing initial value {$a$} (i.e. the value of {$term_1$}); are they notations representing the geometric sequence; or are they a convention used to dictate how {$k$} and {$n$} should be interpreted/used i.e. is {$k-1$} telling you to "shift" the entire progression to the side by one term?

  - Slightly different version of the last point: what exactly does {$k-1$} mean, particularly in regards to {$n$}? There's obviously some rule here because the notation changed from {$n-1$} to {$n$}.

Comment: The $\Sigma$ is a Greek Sigma and is called the *summation operator*.  I would call the various expressions equal to other expressions *equalities* leading to *formulae* for geometric series

Comment: What do you mean by "Why isn't a static value of term - 1,2,3...."? Where do you suggest these terms be used?

Comment: @nochance k and n below and above sigma, these are supposed to represent the first and last terms (ie beginning and end of the sequence of partial sums) is it not ?

Comment: Your Question is difficult to understand.  It seems you don't see any value to using variables in the summation limits rather than constants.  This is really fundamental, to be able to make general statements (and prove them) rather than particular ones.  Facility with changes of variables begins with high school algebra and continues to be an important skill throughout our mathematical journeys.

Comment: The images have a lot of text and formulas that seem to be irrelevant to your question. As near as I can make out, you want to know why there isn't a universal convention that the summation index _always_ starts at $1$ (or a convention that it always starts at $0$), instead of one author choosing $0$ and another choosing $1$. My guess is you don't object to $n$ as the last index. (The word "static", however, makes that guess very uncertain. I don't know what you think that word means in this context.)

Comment: The question might be simpler and clearer if you wrote out the formulas in MathJax format, for example, `$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k$$` (with links to where you got them) rather than posting pictures, and write just enough to show exactly the part you're asking about.

Comment: More information about how to write formulas using MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @hardmath are you using 'limit' to refer to terms and not 'tends to a limit?' I understanding the value of variables here, such as deriving a closed form of the summation.  It wasn't being used for that in the wiki link, it was just representing the first and last terms of the sequence of partial sums.  Is it just a matter of preference whether that's written as [k=1, n, ar^(k-1)] or [k=0, n-1, ar^k]?  I was trying to work out what these 'variables/values' were used for: for instance I thought the [ar^k] was just a convention to identify a sequence of partial sums, or maybe Sk does that.

Comment: @david k yes thats a succint version of my other reply.  I guess it's just preference whether it's k=0 or k=1.  Although I don't understande the point of k=1 because you still have to manually change n to n-1 for the value of the exponent of r for the last term.  Is the ar^k and ar^(k-1) values representing the first term or is it denoting how to use k and n?  For example is ar^(k-1) telling you to subtract 1 from both k AND n?

Comment: @david k also thanks for the mathjax link, that's just what I was looking for

Comment: @david k oops I need to correct, I think what your saying is I'm wondering why the summation index always starts at the first term.  The summation index for both equations starts at the 1st term.  As far as I can tell it's just preference whether k=1 or 0 because because k-1 in ar^(k-1) is still zero for k=0

Comment: @david k you could say I was wondering why there isn't a unvisersal convention to use either k=1 or k=0 when the starting index is the first term. I had already assumed you could change what term you start at but whether that's 1,2,3,4, or 5 the corresponding k value will either be same as the term or be (term value - 1) depending on which version of essentially the same formula above you are using

Comment: I thought that might be the real question. Probably worth editing that into the question (along with other changes you might want to make) rather than just in the comments, but I'm voting to reopen anyway.

Comment: Are you a programmer? I believe I can understand (bits of) your confusion. I'll try to post an answer when I get home.

Comment: We still need one more vote to reopen. Anyone? It's now much clearer and easier to read (nice editing, by the way), and I think this is a good question--not the first question about summation notation, certainly, but it seems (to me) that it touches new points.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thanks, and yeah I started programming last year.

Comment: @user5948022 Let me know if that helps. I was going to write analogies of the sum notation with the `for` cycle, but I believe this was clearer.

Comment: For your information: An automated flag was raised in response to the unusually high number of edits. Those are frowned upon, because every edit moves the question to the front page, and that scarce resource should be used democratically (relying on users following e.g. their favorite tags to get their atttention). If you ever foresee the need to do a lot of editing, you should use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619). Finalize your post there, and then copy/paste the polished version here. It is much less distracting to others, when you do your edits in the sandbox.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Damn. $25$ edits in 20 hours...

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen oops sorry, did not know that (also thought question was on hold?).  Putting the perfectionist away....

Comment: @yotengounlcd haha yeah, I was having a hard time conceptualizing what I was trying to ask.  Probably also having too much fun with the Mathjax David K showed me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start from the bare basics.

Given a sequence $a_n$ (for example, the sequence of even natural numbers $a_1=2,a_2=4,\dots$).

We sometimes **define** a "sequence of partial sums" as $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.

Is it a convention that we should start at $1$? Well, no.

I like to start them at $0$ for example, perhaps some other author likes them starting at $31$, but that doesn't really change much. Anyone who writes something like "Let $s_n$ denote the sequence of partial sums of $a_n$" should make explicit what the starting index is (as a LOT of people either $0$ or $1$ as standard, but this is really arbitrary).

**Remark:** Even if we define $s_n$ as above, we can use this to denote a sum starting at any number we want.

How? Well, what does the expression $s_n-s_{x-1}$ mean (assume $x-1<n$)? From above, we see that

$$
s_n-s_{x-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}a_k=(a_1+\cdots+a_x+\cdots+a_n)-(a_1+\cdots+a_{x-1})\\
=\sum_{k=x}^n a_k
$$

Which is what you wanted!

---

**Second question**

I believe it's easier to see what you're doing this way: consider the sum

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)
$$

This just says: Starting from $0$, up to the number $n$, evaluate $f$ at those points (i.e compute $f(0),f(1),...,f(n)$) and sum them up.

In your example, we have that $f(k)=ar^{k-1}$ (where $a$ denotes some *constant*).

From above, we see that your sum goes from $k=1$ to $k=n$, so all we have to do to compute it is calculate $f(1)=ar^{1-1}=a, f(2)=ar^{2-1},\dots$ and add them up.

---

**Example of index shifting**

Consider the following sum:

$$s=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10$$

I believe you'll agree that I can write this as (see above, with $f(k)=k$)
$$s=\sum_{k=1}^{10} k$$

Now I can write the same thing as
$$
s=(2-1)+(3-1)+(4-1)+\cdots+(11-1)
$$

Or, $$s=\sum_{k=2}^{11} (k-1)$$

Right? Well, from above you can see that these sums are really equal, but the indices and summands look pretty different. Is there any way to go from one to another easily?

Luckily for us, yes. What happens if we call $k-1$ "$u$"? Well, first we note that as $k$ moves from $2$  to $11$, the value of $u$ goes from $1$ to $10$, so we can write

$$
s=\sum_{u=1}^{10}u
$$

Wow! Isn't this the first expression, with just a simple renaming of the variable? :)

---

**Rearrangement of the terms**

I'll give you an example of "switching the order of the sum".

Say we want to write $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\cdots+f(n)$ in sum notation? Well, simple enough, we've seen before that this is just $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$. But what if I want to add this terms in reverse order?

Well, I'll let you figure out if the following works
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f((n+1)-k)
$$

Comment: Great answer, the practical examples given progressively was just what I needed.  Confirmed some of my pre-existing notions and cleared up other points of confusion. Also gave me new stuff I need to mull on so I might be back for some clarification.  On a separate note, I've been on a math binge the last couple of days relying heavily on random tutorials and wikipedia; this has left something to be desired.  You seem to have a knack for pedagogy, could you recommend any good sites/resources for someone who benefits from this kind of presentation?

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Feel free to ask for clarification on anything.
 What are some particular topics you're interested in? I mostly come here when I'm learning new stuff, as the resources are almost endless (and there's lots of nice people willing to help you learn). Besides that, there's always books, but you'll have to be a bit more specific on what you're searching for.

Comment: sorry I was talking about math in paricular.  Any topic pre-calculus and on.  Also anything geared towards the fundmental maths used in finance - I got into summation because of interest rates and inflation.  Thanks

Comment: My last comment wasn't clear enough about the financial math I'm interested in.  Better to say I want to learn about the fundamental math used in financial formulas.  I could memorize (p-p((1+r)^-n))/r as the formula to adjust a mortgage for inflation but I wouldn't understand how that formula was derived.  I could by learning about summation.  It's a shot in the dark asking for such a specific resource so anything on pre-calculus would be great too.

Comment: I see, to be honest, I know nothing about finance (and the kind of mathematics used in that field), but if calc/pre-calc would help you, then I think you should check out Khan Academy (https://www.khanacademy.org/). It's a pretty good resource for learning techniques and building up intuition. After that's acquired, you could grab a nice book to formalize your understandings.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out, thanks